# What happens in this while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

So I learnt the second course of python on edx and here is a code I wrote but don't really understand the part in the while loop. Could someone explain to me like I'm 6 years old what happens there?

Code:

```py
# [ ] Print each word in the quote on a new line  
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
start = 0
space_index = quote.find(" ")

while space_index != -1:  #the code in while needs to be explained to me 
    print(quote[start:space_index])
    start = space_index +1
    space_index = quote.find(" ", space_index +1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to demonstrate how to retrieve a sub-string from a string by index in Python, using a `while` loop having as stop condition that index.

The Python documentation [on the function find() of string is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find). Quoting from it:

[image]

The steps are these:

1. **How to retrieve the index of the first occurrence of a given character in the string `quote`.** In this line: `quote.find(" ")`, it returns the index of the first position of a *whitespace*. So `space_index` will be equal to 4 when the while loop begins.
2. **How to retrieve a sub-string from the string.** In this line: `quote[start:space_index]` if you translate the variables `start` and `space_index`, what you have is: `quote[0,4]` which is equal to "they" in the first iteration.
3. **How to increment the index.** At the end of the `while`, you again do `quote.find(" ", space_index +1)` trying to get the index of a *whitespace* `" "`. But this time the position you start to search from is `space_index+1` which on the first iteration will be 5. The function `quote.find` will return the value 12.
4. **So in the 2nd iteration of the `while`:** you'll be trying to get the sub-string `quote[start:space_index]` or substituting the values: `quote[5:12]` which will be the second word "stumble".

You should try to learn how to use a debugger of the IDE you are using, or try to print all intermediate values so you can see them.

Answer (score 1):

The code basically prints each word separated by space line-by-line.

Commented Snippet:

```
# [ ] Print each word in the quote on a new line  
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
start = 0    ## index of first character
space_index = quote.find(" ")

while space_index != -1:  #the code in while needs to be explained to me 
    print(quote[start:space_index])   ## print characters from start index to space character
    start = space_index +1            ## shift the start index to just after the up-coming space character
    space_index = quote.find(" ", space_index +1)  ## find the index of the next space character
```